# about django HttpResponsePermanentRedirect to android market URL doesn't work

Tags: android, django

when user django HttpResponsePermanentRedirect to redirect :

```
redirect_to = 'market://details?id=com.example.your.package'
if redirect_to:
    return HttpResponsePermanentRedirect(redirect_to)
else :
    return EMPTY_GIF
```

when `redirect_to` is an URL like `http://...` it works fine, but when it is an android market URL the browser (on PC) is always left pending and curl got a 400 (Bad Request)

Answer (score 3):

`market://` is a custom URL scheme for linking to the marketplace app from your smartphone. [Read this guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html#marketintent), you need to link like so:

```
http://play.google.com/store/search?id=<query>
```

**EDIT** 
notice that you can use `search?id=` `search?q=` and `search?pub=` (as mentioned at the bottom of the docs)